# ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I got This error

`ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid internet address jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)`

it's the first time to get this error, and this was the code to post some data

```
      Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'title': "This is my title",
      }),
    
    );
    return x.body;
```

I have searched a lot but no result

note: This was an old version project, i have upgraded flutter while i was working on the project

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This likely is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83792.